# Need help calculating the elements of a sequence

Tags: java, linked-list, time-complexity, sequence

I wrote an algorithm that is supposed to calculate the nth element of a sequence, up to n = 2000000. This sequence is as following:

1 - The first element is 1;

2 - For each element x of the sequence, the elements 2x + 1 and 3x + 1 are also contained in the sequence;

3 - Every element is in ascending order, and there are no duplicate elements;

4 - The sequence has no other values;

such that the first few elements are [1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 13, 15...], seq(50) = 175, seq(50000) = 1237222, seq(1234567) = 71221051, etc.

I wrote the following code:

```
public static long seq(int n) {
    LinkedList<Long> sequence = new LinkedList<>();
    int doubleCount = 0;
    int tripleCount = 0;
    long elementDouble = 1;
    long elementTriple = 0;
    sequence.addLast(elementDouble);
    while (sequence.size() <= n + 2) {
        elementDouble = 2 * sequence.get(doubleCount) + 1; 
        elementTriple = 3 * sequence.get(tripleCount) + 1;
        if (elementDouble < elementTriple && elementDouble > sequence.getLast()) {
            sequence.addLast(elementDouble);
            doubleCount++;
        } else if (elementDouble == sequence.getLast()) {
            doubleCount++;
        } else if (elementTriple > sequence.getLast()) {
            sequence.addLast(elementTriple);
            tripleCount++;
        } else {
            tripleCount++;
        }
    }
    return sequence.get(n);
}
```

which calculates 2x + 1 and 3x + 1 seperately, so that the smallest of the two values is added to the list and the other one stored and compared to its next counterpart.
This gives me the correct results. However, for values of n greater than 1000000, it is extremely slow (over 5 minutes runtime). Is there any way I can improve the code so that I can use it for extremely large instances of n?

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: This question need you to formulate this into some equation. It do not want you to calculate them all. Try to solve it mathematically.

Comment: Also you can do memorization where you can store the already computed values in global array and use them for the next seq(n) call if you can't find the formula and want to stick to the current approach.

Comment: Like for each `n` check if array[n] is not 0 if its not then return it else you need to calculate its value. Now for the calculation I'll first find the greatest number smaller than `n` upto which my sequence has already been calculated. For this I'll use binary search on the array. If mid is not zero I'll go right and if its zero I'll go left then from the last found index I'll start calculating the sequence upto required `n` and meanwhile keep pushing the results for each index in array[]

Comment: With this approach the value for a given `n` is calculated only once during the entire execution of the program. And for faster processing I would say use simple int array rather than list because as far as I know we can create an global array of 10^8 in heap memory

Comment: Correction `return sequence.get(n-1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try maintaining two separate queues, `q1` and `q2`. Make `1` the first element of the sequence, and then enqueue `2*1 + 1 == 3` in `q1` and `3*1 + 1 == 4` in `q2`. The next element of the sequence is the smaller of the two elements at the front of each queue. Dequeue it and call it `x`. The next element of your sequence is `x`, and you can enqueue `2*x + 1` in `q1` and `3*x + 1` in `q2`.

Comment: This also means you don't need to keep track of the elements of the sequence. Just count how many you have dequeued.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does very badly because you're calling `get(index)` on a `LinkedList`. Change to use `ArrayList` will greatly improve performance:

```java
public static long seq(int n) {
    ArrayList<Long> sequence = new ArrayList<>();
    int doubleCount = 0;
    int tripleCount = 0;
    long elementDouble = 1;
    long elementTriple = 0;
    sequence.add(elementDouble);
    while (sequence.size() <= n + 2) {
        elementDouble = 2 * sequence.get(doubleCount) + 1; 
        elementTriple = 3 * sequence.get(tripleCount) + 1;
        if (elementDouble < elementTriple && elementDouble > sequence.get(sequence.size() - 1)) {
            sequence.add(elementDouble);
            doubleCount++;
        } else if (elementDouble == sequence.get(sequence.size() - 1)) {
            doubleCount++;
        } else if (elementTriple > sequence.get(sequence.size() - 1)) {
            sequence.add(elementTriple);
            tripleCount++;
        } else {
            tripleCount++;
        }
    }
    return sequence.get(n);
}
```

*Tests*

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(50);
    test(50000);
    test(1000000);
    test(1234567);
    test(10000000);
    test(100000000);
}
static void test(int n) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    long seq = seq(n);
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.printf("%d: %d (%.9fs)%n", n, seq, (end - start) / 1e9);
}
```

*Output*

```
50: 175 (0.000202500s)
50000: 1237222 (0.008792100s)
1000000: 54381286 (0.100169600s)
1234567: 71221051 (0.084787500s)
10000000: 1031926810 (0.454602800s)
100000000: 19115394879 (4.044839300s)
```